# ошибка при отправке POST запроса

Tags: python

Есть форма клиента Tkinter с двумя кнопками, к каждой привязана функция, которые пытаюсь послать на сервер. По первой функции получаю ответ от сервера, а по второй приходит ошибка.

Почему так происходит и как это можно исправить?

**The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.**

Код клиента:

```
import requests
from tkinter import *

def relay_proverka(name):
    url = 'http://localhost:5000/'
    data = {'man': name}
    e = requests.post(url, data)
    print(e.text)


def relay_proverka_sliv(drain):
    url = 'http://localhost:5000/'
    data = {'drain': drain}
    e = requests.post(url, data)
    print(e.text)
```

Код сервера

```
from flask import Flask, request
from poliv import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def button1():
    f = request.form['man']
    p = man_pour_em(f)
    return p

def button2():
    f = request.form['drain']
    p = drain_em(f)
    return p


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000)
```

Comment: Какие значения у параметров `man` и `drain`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка тут не одна:

1. В коде клиента по обеим кнопкам Вы обращаетесь в один и тот же URL: `/`
2. В коде сервера обработчик второй кнопки в принципе недоступен извне.

В итоге, запрос со второй кнопки летит в `button1()`, который пытается взять аргумент `man`, но его там нет, поэтому кидается ошибка, что Вы и наблюдаете.

---

Решение простое – направить в клиенте запросы на разные нужные юрлы (строки 1 и 2), а также настроить их обработку на сервере (3 и 4).

Клиент:

```
import requests
from tkinter import *

def relay_proverka(name):
    url = 'http://localhost:5000/button1'  # 1
    data = {'man': name}
    e = requests.post(url, data)
    print(e.text)


def relay_proverka_sliv(drain):
    url = 'http://localhost:5000/button2'  # 2
    data = {'drain': drain}
    e = requests.post(url, data)
    print(e.text)
```

Сервер:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from poliv import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/button1', methods=['POST'])  # 3
def button1():
    f = request.form['man']
    p = man_pour_em(f)
    return p

@app.route('/button2', methods=['POST'])  # 4
def button2():
    f = request.form['drain']
    p = drain_em(f)
    return p


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000)
```